# Unset ing class to clear memory

Tags: php

I'm using [twitter-async](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-async-documentation.html) library to interact with twitter api. However, the memory limit keeps increasing even if I use `gc_enable()` and `gc_collect_cycles()` after various unset()s

Before using garbage collector, memory usage was too much. It has certainly decreased a lot. But not satisfactorily.

I'm running a for loop that checks for new requests in database and processes them.

Suppose, a request is processed, generating around 98 MB (this is fine -- considering the amount of data I'm fetching from twitter) of memory, and there are no more requests to be processed, then this 98 MB of data will stay forever until php reaches the 260MB memory limit I have setup. I've already setup monit that restarts the script if it crashes due to memory limit.

After investigating a bit, I found that the library saves data about failed calls,etc in some variables. Is there a way with which I can destroy the entire class that will unset all the memory-hungry variables and save the memory? I'm currently just unset()ing the variable for the class.

```
$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter();
// Do all the stuff ..
unset($twitterObj);
```

But there still isn't any change in memory usage.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if any other object keeps reference to either `$twitterObj` itself or some big data inside it. You could define a destructor `__destruct()` for the class to see if the object is actually destroyed (it is called on actual destruction).

I would also recommend using a profiler - such as [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) or [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) or [Zend products](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/) - to see memory usage and find where the memory is wasted.

Comment: I'm trying this out. Will post an update soon. But I have a strong feeling that this will work. Had thought about it, but never tried it myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

`unset` only does what it says it does: unset the variable. It doesn't immediately free it. PHP will do that later automatically - by intention as soon, as those CPU cycles aren't needed, or as late as before the script would run out of memory; whatever occurs first.

<s>To immediately free memory, you'll need to rewrite the variable's data. Try this:</s>

```
$twitterObj = null;
```

Comment: $twitterObj = null would do exactly the same as unset($twitterObj)

Comment: @StatM, thanks. I wasn't sure of that. The first part of my answer still stands.

Answer (score 1):

`unset` will not free the memory. It will only remove the reference between variable and object. The Garbage Collector will free the memory next time it is run unless there is other references to the object elsewhere. As of PHP5.3, you can force gc'ing by calling

- [`gc_collect_cycles` — Forces collection of any existing garbage cycles](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php)

For a more detailed explanation, see the [PHP Manual on Garbage Collection](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php).

Comment: How do I find if the object is being referenced anywhere?

Comment: @KPL With http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php - if it has a refcount, it's referenced